# web.xml changes to enable development mode in Groovlet

Tags: groovy, jetty, web.xml

I am using the Cruise Control jetty container to deploy a Groovlet application. It appears that if I change the groovy files in the webapp directory that Jetty does not recompile the source and the changes aren't reflected in the webapp. How can I modify my web.xml file to check for updates on every load? I'm just using a simple web.xml:

```
<web-app>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>GroovyServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>groovy.servlet.GroovyServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>GroovyServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.groovy</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>myApp.groovy</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Comment: It certainly looks like you should be getting the results you're after. Are you 100% sure that it's not working (perhaps your browser is caching things?)

Answer (score 0):

GroovyScriptEngine checks the last-modification date of the source file. If it is newer than the last cache entry, a recompile will certainly done.